# Castle remoting facility not working

Tags: castle-windsor, remoting

Does remoting facility still work in castle?

i downloaded sample from http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/remoting/usingit.html
 changed project to target 4.0 of framework.

Then I deleted references to castle in both client and server projects and then added references to Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor dlls from castles "bin-dotNet40" folder.

When I run the server I get the follwoing exception:
Could not convert from 'Castle.Facilities.Remoting.RemotingFacility, Castle.MicroKernel' to System.Type - Maybe type could not be found

thanks for responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Castle.MicroKernel.dll is no more (it was merged into Castle.Windsor.dll), so the correct fully qualified type name is now `Castle.Facilities.Remoting.RemotingFacility, Castle.Windsor`

Comment: Thanks Mauricio. I changed this as you suggested and my server is up and running.However my client is throwing the following exception: Could not set up component 'remote.console.component'. Type 'System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not implement service 'Example.Shared.IRemoteConsole, Example.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. I have not changed anything in registering this component and would expect it to work. Any suggests? thanks

Comment: @Noel: please create a new question with more details. How are you registering the facility? How are you loading the xml config? Which scenario are you using?

Comment: Thanks Mauricio. I have posted a question on this issue @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557796/castle-remoting-sample-client-throwing-exception